# Как добиться параллельного выполнения двух функций в kernel linux?

Tags: linux, kernel, распараллеливание

С помощью чего можно реализовать параллельное выполнение двух и более функций в kernel-mode? 
Распараллеливание происходит на процессорах с 2-мя и более ядрами?

Comment: Само по себе оно не происходит. https://habrahabr.ru/company/embox/blog/244071/

Comment: А простой пример есть?